# Solr highlighting with Phrase query not working as expected

Tags: solr, nosql, highlighting

I have a strange problem. I am running a highlighting query with following data

```
{ id: 1,
  fld: 'a word1 a word2 a word3 a word4 a word5' }
```

The query,

```
q=fld:"a word1 a word2 a word3"&fl=fld,id&hl=on&hl.fl=fld
```

and I get the highlighting in the output as

```
"a <em>word1</em> a <em>word2</em> a <em>word3</em> a word4 a word5"
```

However, when I change the query to

```
q=fld:"a word1 a word2 a word3 a word4"&fl=fld,id&hl=on&hl.fl=fld
```

It doesn't give anything in highlighting section, it gives the doc in result section though

The field `fld` is of type `text_en` and I haven't modified the fieldType in schema.

Can someone point whats the mistake here?

Comment: Салман, i am facing same problem, did you find any workaround?

Comment: @VishalParekh I used `PositionFilterFactory` and it worked. The problem is due to `stopwords`.